# How to kill process ran by parent process when parent process is killed?

Tags: ubuntu, process, docker

I am running multiple docker containers via python script. I already handled to kill all dockers when gracefully (cltr+c) shutdown the python script but when it's forced killed, the docker remains running.

Question is, is there a way to kill the docker containers if the python script is killed ungracefully? (Perhaps setting the python script as parent process to the docker process? Is there such thing?)

Comment: Why do you use a python script and not `docker-compose`?

Comment: I have a service using docker. the python serves as the service manager that runs multiple docker-compose via bash.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having the same problem, this might help.

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
def set_pdeathsig(sig=signal.SIGTERM):
    def callback():
        return libc.prctl(1, sig)
    return callback

open_container_cmd = "docker-compose run --rm test" # cannot use detach <-d>
proc = subprocess.Popen(
                open_container_cmd,
                shell=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                preexec_fn=set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM))
```